# Lagrange's theorem related question please?

Tags: limits

I have to prove that $\ln(x) > 3*[(x-1)]/(x+1)$ for $x > 1$...

Using Lagrange's theoreme... I have no idea where to start because I dont even have an interval? Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Aren't you working over the interval $(1, \infty)$?

Comment: Yes but I need an interval like a<b<c right?

Comment: Are you sure the $3$ should be there?

Comment: yes.im pretty sure

Comment: it's written like that in the book I bought -.-

Comment: @djsakds As I showed in my answer, this does not hold. Your book must have a typo

Comment: What *exactly* do you call "Lagrange's Theorem" to within this context?

Comment: @DonAntonio I suppose he means the Mean Value Theorem

Comment: @Nameless, I'm almost 100% positive he did, yet I think it's a good idea to be more explicit when writing to an international audience. Thanks.

Comment: @djsakds, what is that book you bought?

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is not true for say $x=2$. Then you have
$$\ln 2>3\frac{2-1}{2+1}=3\frac13=1$$ which is not true because $\ln 2<\ln e=1$

I suspect the correct inequality is $$\ln x>\frac{x-1}{x}\iff \frac{\ln x-\ln 1}{x-1}>\frac{1}{x}$$
If so consider the interval $(1,x)$